# How to filter dataframe based on single exact match in data group using Pandas

Tags: pandas

my `df` looks like this:

```
student_id,    coll_type,    completed    
1001           2-year        N          
1001           2-year        N           
1001           2-year        Y           
1001           4-year        Y            

1002           4-year        N              
1002           2-year        N                   
1002           2-year        N                   
1002           2-year        Y                   

1003           4-year        N                    
1003           4-year        N                    

1004           2-year        N                   
1004           2-year        Y
```

**I am trying to accomplish 3 things:**

- student_id who *only* went to `coll_type` `2-year` for the student_id group
- student_id who *only* went to `coll_type` `4-year` for the student_id group
- student_id who *only* went to both `coll_type` `2-year` and `4-year` for the student_id group
- finally, I want to have 3 different dataframe from the original dataframe

**What did I do ?**

I tried to do it this way to get only `2-year` but it does not work 100% as expected.

```
 df[~(df['coll_type']=='4-year')]
```

the reason it does not work as expected is because it will also give me `student_id` who also went to `4-year` but only returns their `2-year` data.

how do I only get the data in which student_id only went to respective `coll_type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a category column based on `coll_type` as follows and then group or filter based on the `category` column:

```
def categorize(coll_type: pd.Series):
    """
    takes a Series as parameter, returns 0 if all values are 2-year
    returns 1 if all values are 4-year. Otherwise return 2
    """
    if (coll_type == '2-year').all():
        return 0
    elif (coll_type == '4-year').all():
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

df['category'] = df.coll_type.groupby(df.student_id).transform(categorize)

df
    student_id coll_type completed  category
0         1001    2-year         N         2
1         1001    2-year         N         2
2         1001    2-year         Y         2
3         1001    4-year         Y         2
4         1002    4-year         N         2
5         1002    2-year         N         2
6         1002    2-year         N         2
7         1002    2-year         Y         2
8         1003    4-year         N         1
9         1003    4-year         N         1
10        1004    2-year         N         0
11        1004    2-year         Y         0
```

To further get 2-year / 4-year student ids, just do a filter:

```
df[df.category == 0].student_id.unique()
# array([1004], dtype=int64)

df[df.category == 1].student_id.unique()
# array([1003], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: thanks for working on it. what I am trying to do is only filter if their `coll_type` is `2-year` data. the `student_id` can have both `2-year`  and `4-year` but I do not want those `student_id`. just the `student_id` with exact `coll_type` `2-year`.. after that I can do the same for only `4-year`

Comment: category == 0 will be 2-year data. category == 1 will be 4-year data.  And you can filter by the category. Does that not work ?

Comment: More specificially `df[df.category == 0].student_id.unique()` and `df[df.category == 1].student_id.unique()`

Comment: in the output above, there is also a `category = 2` and the categories does not match for each `coll_year`. In addition, I need to get only `student_id` if they `only` went to `coll_type` `2-year` not both  `2-year` and  `4-year`

Comment: Please see my 2nd comment  - An  extra  filter will give  you the student ids you need.

Comment: Gotcha! I see what you mean. thank you!

Comment: is there a way to do this a bit faster?

Comment: Is this not fast enough ? How big your  data is ?